# Why after restaring Tor in TAILS the GUI thinks it is not started?

Tags: tails, vidalia

After starting TAILS, there is GUI that shows Tor status.

But after I do `/etc/init.d/tor restart` as root (because of sometimes it gets stuck due to clock jumps), the "Vidalia control panel" shows "Tor is not running" and Tor-browser warns "Tor is not running. Do you really want to start?", even tough it is actually running and tor-browser works if I press "Yes".

Why does it happen? How do I restart Tor correctly on TAILS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because Vidalias and TorBrowser are detecting that Tor has stopped, and but they didn't auto-detect that it has started right afterwards. It's a bug, but nothing to worry about, since you can normally run TorBrowser and other Tor-related staff after that.

Comment: Shall I file a bug to TAILS?

Comment: Yes, better do that.

Comment: Is [this](https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/7614) a request about my problem or I should file a new one?

Comment: No, that's a separate one. However, since Vidalia is no longer maintained, you should probably on focus on TorBrowser behavior only in the bug you're going to file.

Comment: Submitted: https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/8856